# Utilização do DataTables no cakephp

Tags: mysql, ajax, jquery-datatables, cakephp-3

Gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar com Datatables (server-side processing) no cakephp (versão 3.0 em diante). Consegui fazer no php e está funcionando. Entretanto, quando tento utilizar a mesma ideia no cakephp, não estou conseguindo.
Já pesquisei bastante na internet e não achei nada que me ajudasse.
Este código abaixo, lista todos os registros no DataTable mas não limita o número de registros, pesquisa ou qualquer outra ação que queira fazer na Datatable.

```html
class UsersController extends AppController
{

    public function index()
    {

        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

         {
             $statement = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Users");
             $statement->execute();
             $resultado = $statement->fetchAll();
             $totalReg= $statement->rowCount();
         }

        $query = $this->Users->find();



            if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
            {
                $query .= 'WHERE Title LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
                $query .= 'OR Description LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
                $query .= 'OR Release LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
                $query .= 'OR Rating LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
                $query .= 'OR id LIKE "%'.$_POST["search"]["value"].'%" ';
            }

            if(isset($_POST["order"]))
            {
                $query .= ' ORDER BY '.$_POST['order']['0']['column'].' '.$_POST['order']['0']['dir'].' ';
            }
            else
            {
            $query .= ' ORDER BY id DESC ';
            }
  

            $statement = $connection->prepare($query);
            $statement->execute();  
            $resultado = $statement->fetchAll();
            $dados = array();
            $contar_rows = $statement->rowCount();

        foreach($resultado as $row)
        {

            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[] = $row["0"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["1"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["2"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["3"];
            $sub_array[] = $row["4"];
            $dados[] = $sub_array;
            
        }

        $saida = array(
            "draw"              =>  intval(["draw"]),
            "recordsTotal"      =>  $contar_rows,
            "recordsFiltered"   => $totalReg,
            "data"              =>  $dados
        );


     if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
                return $this->response
                     ->withStatus(200)
                    ->withStringBody(json_encode($saida));
             }

    }
   }
```

```html
//index.php do TEMPLATE

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.25/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": "<?= Cake\Routing\Router::url(['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'index']) ?>",
                "type": "POST"
            },
                    "oLanguage": {
                                "sProcessing":   "Processando...",
                                "sLengthMenu":   "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
                                "sZeroRecords":  "Não foram encontrados resultados",
                                "sInfo":         "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                                "sInfoEmpty":    "Mostrando de 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                                "sInfoFiltered": "",
                                "sInfoPostFix":  "",
                                "sSearch":       "Buscar:",
                                "sUrl":          "",
                                "oPaginate": {
                                    "sFirst":    "Primeiro",
                                    "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                                    "sNext":     "Seguinte",
                                    "sLast":     "Último"
                                }
                            }

        } );
    } );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Release</th>
                <th>Rating</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Release</th>
                <th>Rating</th>

            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Sua pergunta pode ser melhorada ao apresentar um exemplo reproduzível para que possamos comentar. Sugerir onde buscar exemplos não é o objetivo daqui.

Comment: Já inseri o código. Aguardo sugestões.